# JavaScript Syntax : passing json in function as params

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I came across below syntax while I was writing test cases for one existing code base .

```
export function * downloadDataSaga({payload: {stateObject ,fieldObject}}){
//Some code 



}
```

Kindly help me in understanding this syntax where json type syntax is used as params in function.I.e which feature of JavaScript is this and what does this syntax mean ?

Comment: That is not JSON.

Comment: read about [function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) (generator function) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: It is object destrucuring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: It's a generator function. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator